# Nuxtjs canonical URL are getting overridden on production

Tags: nuxt.js, seo, amazon-cloudfront, canonical-link, canonicalization

I've a nuxt application, that is deployed using S3 and CF on AWS. The canonical URL is getting changed on production, but working correctly on localhost. Here is my folder structure:

[image]

### ISSUE:

Inside these pages I've added `head()` function and added canonical tags custom to each page. Say, For `./blogs` home page, below is the code:

```
  head() {
    return {
      title: 'StackWealth Blog: Financial Insights & Investment Tips',
      meta: [
        {
          hid: 'description',
          name: 'description',
          content: '...'
        }
      ],
      link: [
        {
          hid: 'canonical',
          rel: 'canonical',
          href: `https://stackwealth.in/blogs`
        }
      ]
    };
  },
```

If I check this on localhost, the link tag is coming correctly. But as soon as I build and deploy to production, this URL automatically get replaced by `https://stackwealth.in/` i.e. removing route names from the host URL.

Here is my **nuxt.config.js**:

```
import { getBlogRoutes } from './utils';
require('dotenv').config();


export default {
  ssr: true,
  server: {
    port: process.env.PORT || 5100,
    host: '0.0.0.0' // default: localhost
  },
  head: {
    title: '...',
    meta: [
      {
        charset: 'utf-8'
      },
      {
        hid: 'description',
        name: 'description',
        content: '...'          
      },
      ...
    ],
    link: [
      {
        rel: 'icon',
        type: 'image/x-icon',
        href: '/favicon.png'
      }
    ]
  },
  css: [
    '@/assets/scss/app.scss'
  ],
  plugins: [...],
  buildModules: ['nuxt-compress'],
  modules: [
   ...
  ],
  generate: {
    routes: () => getBlogRoutes() /// there is Util function that pull all dynamic URLs
  },
  ...  
};
```

### Expectations:

The URL inside `href` of  `<link rel="canonical" href="...">` should be the link of page instead of the host URL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So basically, the page was loading with a 403 error

```
------ Error page for 403:--------
Error Caching Minimum TTL   10s
Response Page Path /index.html
HTTP Response Code  200
---------------------
```

Since I've subdirectories such as http://www.example.com/about/. The index.html needs to be added after the subdirectory i.e "https://www.example.com/about/index.html" so the page will load without 403 errors.

So for this I've done a few steps.

1. All the URLs should end with a trailing `/`. i.e., https://example.co/about should be https://example.co/about/. This can be done by adding `trailingSlash: true` inside `router` key of `nuxt.config.js`. **Don't forget to change all `<NuxtLink to="">` code inside your HTML or if you're using this.$route.path('')**
2. Add a `redirect.js` file inside `./middleware/` of the project and include this file again in `nuxt.config.js` inside `serverMiddleware` key. This file will contain the code to redirect all the URL that are not ending with `/` to the URL ending with `/`. Check code below.
3. Now on AWS I've followed [this documentation](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/implementing-default-directory-indexes-in-amazon-s3-backed-amazon-cloudfront-origins-using-lambdaedge/) to create Lambda@Edge function for redirection.

PS - Make sure while editing the AWS Lambda you are saving the details. Also, somehow L@E Node.js 18.x was throwing ES6 module error, so use `export const handler = async () => {}` instead of `exports.handler = async () => {}`. Weird but yeah!

#### redirect.js

```
const redirect= (req, res, next) => {
  const uri = req.url;
  if (!uri.endsWith('/')) {
    res.writeHead(301, { Location: uri + '/' });
    res.end();
  } else {
    next();
  }
};

export default redirect;
```

Answer (score 0):

You probably used a component inside the page and inside that component you change the canonical value in the head tag.

Comment: I've checked components through out there is no such issue. Plus this is not just one page problem, all other pages are facing same issue.